# ASP.net webforms DateTime format issue on change of web server

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

My application written in ASP.NET webforms was working fine on web server, but after hosting company changes the server, on new server its getting datetime errors, is there any way to write server agnostic universal datetime code in ASP.NET?

My code is as follows: I fetch financial year date range as follows

```
if (rd["StartDate"] == DBNull.Value)
{
    this.StartDate = new DateTime();
}
else
{
    this.StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(rd["StartDate"]);
}

if (rd["EndDate"] == DBNull.Value)
{
    this.EndDate = new DateTime();
}
else
{
    this.EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(rd["EndDate"]);
}
```

Then in webforms, I compare it with user inputs bill date

```
if (!DateTime.TryParse(txtbilldate.Text, cul, DateTimeStyles.None, out billdate))
{
    ucMessage.Visible = true;
    ucMessage.ShowErrorMsg("Invalid bill Date");
    txtbilldate.Focus();
    return;
}
```

It was working fine, now on new server it is not working anymore

Comment: You don't mention what kind of object "rd" is here. And you don't mention if the data table (a guess on my part), has a string type of value, or it is a datetime, or a sql date column? That information is important here. It sounds like you were "lucky" that the code worked before.  You also don't mention/note/show/supply what kind of var this.EndDate is? What type of object/var type is "enddate".

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal "rd" is DataReader, the code fetch data from SQL SERVER Database and set it to local variable, and when user input the date in web form, it compares the input against dates fetched from DB,

Answer (score 0):

Hum, you don't show what this.StartDate is???

should you not be using this:

```
 this.StartDate = DateTime.Today;
```

The above of course does not include the time portion (which I assume you don't want a time part, but just a date part).

so say this:

```
        DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Today;
        DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Now;

        Debug.Print(dt1.ToString());
        Debug.Print(dt2.ToString());
```

Output:

```
1/3/2023 12:00:00 AM
1/3/2023 10:14:07 PM
```

So, my guess here (and I stress "guess"), is this assigment:

```
this.StartDate = new DateTime();
```

Should not that be:

```
DateTime StartDate;  // defined at page class level???

this.StartDate = DateTime.Today;
```